# How to replace the txt file in a directory

Tags: python

There is directory A, which contains several subdirectories of txt files. There is another directory B, which contains txt files. There are several txt files in A that have the same name in B but different content. Now I want to move the txt files in B to A and cover the files with the same name. My Code is as below:

```
 import shutil
 import os
 src = '/PATH/TO/B'
 dst = '/PATH/TO/A'
 file_list = []

 for filename in os.walk(dst):
    file_list.append(filename)

 for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for file in files:

        if file in file_list:
            ##os.remove(dst/file[:-4] + '.txt')
            shutil.move(os.path.join(src,file),os.path.join(dst,file))
```

But when I run this, it did nothing. Can anyone help me about it?

Comment: At a glance it looks fine. Try adding some logging statements to see which part of the program produces which results.

Comment: My suspicion is that `file_list` is empty or a list of tuples because the `os.walk` function returns a tuple, not just filename. You might need to use a similar `for` statement to the one used to walk the `src` dir. Also, your src path will not be correct in the second loop since all you have is the filename and not the full path. Joining the root dir of `src` will not be the correct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do what you want. You need to be careful to preserve the subdirectory structure so as to avoid `FileNotFound` exceptions. Test it out in a test directory before clobbering the actual directories you want modified so you know that it does what you want.

```
import shutil
import os
src = 'B'
dst = 'A'
file_list = []
dst_paths = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dst):
    for file in files:
        full_path = os.path.join(root, file)
        file_list.append(file)
        dst_paths[file] = full_path

print(file_list)
print(dst_paths)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):
    for file in files:
        if file in file_list:
            b_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            shutil.move(b_path,dst_paths[file])
```

Comment: Hi @Ashley if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.